# how do I add a url parameter to a routelink in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

All, my situation is that I have the basic route, plus some other simple routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = 1}
            );
```

So the following url works: **http://somesite.com/tags/index/1**

However, some of my index pages take url parameters in the following fashion:

**http://somesite.com/tags/index/1?when=lastmonth**

**How do I use Html.RouteLink to link to this?**

You **can't** add '?' to routes in the global asax file like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("TagsWhen", "Tags/index/{id}?when={when}",
      new {controller = "Tags", action = "Index", id = "", when = ""});
```

If this route worked I could link to it using:

```
Html.RouteLink(string.Format("{0} ", link.Rating), "LinksWhen", 
               new {id=link.ReferenceId, when=Model.When})
```

but it doesn't! So I'm not sure how I would use a Html.RouteLink to generate http://somesite.com/tags/index/1?when=lastmonth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution myself. You can just do a regular Html.RouteLink and any object properties you don't have mapped to the url in global.asax it adds as a url parameter.

So using this route:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Links",                                              
        "Links/details/{id}",                           
        new { controller = "Links", action = "Details", id = ""} defaults
    );
```

and this routelink:

```
Html.RouteLink("Link Text", "Links", 
        new {id=link.ReferenceId, when=Model.When })
```

generates the correct url:

http://localhost:2535/Links/details/1?when=onemonth

Comment: You should still be able to base this off an ActionLink. I don't know why Matthew's solution didn't work? I do the same thing as him using ActionLink where I have a url: .../delete/124?otherId=5

Comment: Plus if you use a RouteLink, your adding another dependency, the "Links" route name must always exist and you're tying the name to a ref. in your view (if you ever do change the name you'll hit an exception too). Because you have a standard route though, an `ActionLink` would be fine and then you don't need code for it's own separate named route.

Comment: I'm curious. Why would you want to create an 'ugly' url when you could have a pretty one?!

Answer (score 0):

Matthew's approach probably didn't work because he needed another `null` parameter on the end, otherwise it passes the route values as html attributes. :)

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Link text", "Index", "Home", new { id = 1, when = "lastmonth" }, null) %>
```

That last `MapRoute()` you came up with should work fine against it.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a computer able to test this, but off the top of my head

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Link text", "Index", "Home", new { id = 1, when = "lastmonth" } %>
```

You don't need to specify optional parameters in your routes in the global.asax.cs file.  Anything that doesn't match gets chucked into the query string by default.

Comment: but wouldn't that generate an improper url?

Comment: Just tried this, and it generates:
http://somesite.com/tags/index?when=lastmonth

and doesn't add the id...

Comment: Question specifically says `RouteLink`, not `ActionLink`.